# Seaeching and appending strings in unix

Tags: unix

I have a file I want to search for line that has a certain world and append a sentence at its end
How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cat test.txt |sed 's/searchString/&addedString/' > new.txt

"&" refer to the matched string. Here is the real example

```
qifei@qifei] cat test.txt                                                                                                                                                                                     ~
aaaa
bbbb
cccc
aaaa
qifei@qifei] cat test.txt |sed 's/aaaa/&bbbb/' > new.txt                                                                                                                                                                                  ~
qifei@qifei] cat new.txt                                                                                                                                                                                                                  ~
aaaabbbb
bbbb
cccc
aaaabbbb
```

Comment: It works but here I redirect it to a new file I want the change to be in the old how can I do that?

Comment: sed -i.bak 's/aaaa/&bbbb/g' test.txt  (-i store a backup)